# German umlaut on Danish keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use standard Danish QWERTY keyboard (on Debian, if the distro matters). Is it at all possible to write German umlauts such as Ä, Ö, Ü by some key combos (that is without changing the layout to German)?

Comment: It's possible even in a Portuguese keyboard, and we don't have umlauts! If you have dead keys (as I do), combining them with `Alt Gr` and `Shift` will likely make you able to write characters of any language with the Latin alphabet. Plus, you can load keyboard layouts per session if you prefer. That kind of internationalization I love is something missing in Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key between Å and Enter should produce a "dead diaeresis". I.e. pressing the <kbd>¨</kbd> key followed by <kbd>u</kbd> should produce `ü`.

I'm not Danish so I'm basing this on my knowledge of the Finnish/Swedish keyboard and Wikipedia.

[image: Danish keyboard from wikipedia]

Answer (score 4):

On my system (UK keyboard),

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep dead_diaeresis
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft bracketleft braceleft dead_diaeresis dead_abovering dead_diaeresis
```

The fact that it is in 5th position in there means that it's obtained in combination with the `ISO_Level3_Shift` key.

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key
```

You can locate what key they are using:

```
xkbprint -label code "$DISPLAY" keyboard.ps
```

And look at the generated PostScript file (for instance with `evince` or `gv`).

On my keyboard, the `ISO_Level3_Shift` (keycode 108) key is marked <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the one with the dead diaeresis (keycode 34) is marked <kbd>[</kbd>.

So if I type <kbd>AltGr+[</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+A</kbd>, I get `Ä`.

You'll notice above that the second field for that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key (which is when combined with <kbd>Shift</kbd>) is `Multi_key` aka `Compose`. So, to get a `Ä`, I can also type <kbd>Shift+AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>.